# How to "Print" Excel Sheet on Custom Page Size like Din A1?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have excel 2016 and I created a big sheet, and I want to "print" it out on Din A1 paper. Meaning that I want to save it as pdf first and sending it out to the printing service.

I have set the sheet to fit on one page in the "Page Setup" (see Screenshot).

[image: Page Setup]

Next I want to print it on A2 or A1, therefore I chose "Manage Custom Sizes..." from the "Paper Size:"-Dropdown and set the custom size for Din A2 and Din A1:

[image: Custom Page Size]

Though the result looks like this:

[image: Print Result]

As you can see, the sheet should cover the whole page, but it doesn't with this particular custom size.

Neither does it fit to any other custom size, which is above **297mm x 420mm**, which is the supported DinA3 size.

When I use as a custom size **297mm x 420mm** the sheet fits the page good, but even if the custom size is just **1mm** off, the results breaks.

See the following example with **297mm x 421mm**:

[image]

How do I print out this Excel Sheet on ONE custom page with a custom size? (Like Din A1 with **594mm x 841mm**)

Thanks in advance.

Btw: I am on Mac. Not sure if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could try converting the pdf into an image, for example png then use a word processor to stretch the image as desired, without losing image quality that is